# Android: Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError (4.4.2 on Samsung)

Tags: android, android-multidex

This crash appears only on Samsung with 4.4.2 SDK version and in rooted mode (Crashlytics informations):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/graphics/drawable/Icon
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java)
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:656)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.getExportedPropertyMethods(ViewDebug.java:960)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.exportMethods(ViewDebug.java:1047)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:997)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:983)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpView(ViewDebug.java:900)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:870)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dump(ViewDebug.java:793)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dispatchCommand(ViewDebug.java:416)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$W.executeCommand(ViewRootImpl.java:6258)
       at android.view.IWindow$Stub.onTransact(IWindow.java:65)
       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.graphics.drawable.Icon" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xxx-1.apk", zip file "/data/data/com.xxx/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.xxx-1.apk.classes2.zip"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.xxx-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java)
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:656)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.getExportedPropertyMethods(ViewDebug.java:960)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.exportMethods(ViewDebug.java:1047)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:997)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:983)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpView(ViewDebug.java:900)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:870)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dump(ViewDebug.java:793)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dispatchCommand(ViewDebug.java:416)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$W.executeCommand(ViewRootImpl.java:6258)
       at android.view.IWindow$Stub.onTransact(IWindow.java:65)
       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java)
```

I can't understand why. My projet is correctly configured with Dex notion:

In Gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 19 // Min SDK supported by this app (= KITKAT)
    targetSdkVersion 26 // SDK dedicated for this app

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true

    ...

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

    ...
```

And My App extends MultiDexApp:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ...
```

Have you got some explanations about this crash?

Thank you very much guys

Comment: (not a solution, personal opinion) If there's a single incident of a crash that happened once on a single device, where you can't trace the issue to a root source in your code, just ignore it. you can most likely not fix it

Comment: did you added MultiDex.install(this); in oncreate() of your MyApplication ?

Comment: @SudheeshR of course because I extend MultiDexApplication class

Comment: did you tried this in gradle ? : dexOptions { javaMaxHeapSize "4g" preDexLibraries = false }

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced the same error in Xiaomi Device with Android 4.4. You can solve the problem by adding the multidex in `attachBaseContext()` and with the plain Application:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

  @Override protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
  }

}
```

Then add the following code to your app `build.gradle`:

```
android {

  ...

    dexOptions {
      jumboMode true
      javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    } 
  ...
}
```

I've tested the code on Android 4.1, 4.4, 5.0, and 6.0

Answer (score 0):

Multidex is working very unstable prior to Android 5.0. I can't run it properly for 2 my projects. Try to update all build tools to last version and Disable instant Run. For example some libraris not support multidex - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63999442